# How to make terminal input invisible in Ada?

Tags: ada, gnat, ada2012

I need to secure input passwords in an Ada command line application. Are there  any ready to use functions/procedures in GNAT or third-party libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the free third party package that corresponds my needs. [Trendy_Terminal](https://github.com/pyjarrett/trendy_terminal) has a procedure for temporally disabling terminal echo in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jrcarter/Encryption-utilities has Password_Line, which does this. It works with GNAT and ObjectAda on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thk. I looked at it. Unfortunately i need a "more comprehensive solution". I need to handle arrows / delete / backspace and other control keys, as well as CTRL+V and non-latin symbols.